# Flutter reverse order of Children inside Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to reverse the order of Children inside Column?
Because I'm using a custom Widget and the widget appears two times: first time the order is good, the second time order is reversed.

**Need to reverse the order of Text elements in Column**:

```
Column(
          verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
          children: [
            Text(
              dTDInfoValue,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: AppFontSizes.aboutMountainDTDInfoText,
                  color: AppColors.aboutMountainDTDInfoColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: AppConstants.aboutMountainDTDSizedBoxHeight),
            Text(
              dTDInfoName,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: AppFontSizes.aboutMountainDTDNameText,
                  color: AppColors.aboutMountainDTDInfoNameColor),
            )
          ],
        )
```

Comment: verticalDirection  does not the job?

Comment: It did, just that hot reload didn't work, needed to hot restart to see the changes, yeah so this question is dumb now

Answer (score 2):

Use the `List<Widget>` to store the `Widget` you need.

```
List<Widget> _widgetList = [/* your Widgets */];

Column(
          verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
          children: [
            for(int i=0; i<_widgetList.length; i++)
              _widgetList[i];
          ],
        )
```

Use the `reversed` method of List to reverse the order.

```
_widgetList.reversed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the order of item, It will be easier to make a list and then reverse if needed.

You can do something like

```dart
body: Column(
  // verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
  children: [
    ...[
      Text(
        "XdTDInfoValue",
        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 100),
      Text(
        "dTDInfoName",
      ),
    ].reversed.map((e) => e).toList()
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a state variable of type  List
say

```
List<Widget>myList=[Widget1, Widget2, Widget3...],
```

and to reverse use method `myList.reversed`.

Assign this variable to Column children and use `myList.reversed` within setState whenever you need to reverse the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> randomWords = ['abc', 'xyz', '123'];

List<String> reversedRandomWords = randomWords.reversed.toList();

print(reversedRandomWords); // [ '123','xyz', 'abc'];
```